# Php does not get Ajax`s sent values

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I sent this ajax request to php:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "php/getInfo.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        lat: 51.4818048,
        log: -0.5275648
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            
        }   
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
})
```

this is the php:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

    $url=`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=` . $_REQUEST['lat'] . `+` . $_REQUEST['log'] . `MY API KEY`;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

I replaced the API key that I have, the problem is in the response for the data key I get null.

I know it might be a foolish question and I apologise in advance.

Comment: If you hard code the lat/log values in your PHP script does it run? Have you tried dumping the $_REQUEST variable to see what comes across? Have you tried putting quotes around the values like `data:{lat: '51.4818048',log:'-0.5275648'}`

Comment: So I gave the hard coded values but in the app I use a function that takes the values from somewhere else , But the values come out to this. I just gave the hard coded values for simplicity so I don't give too much code. I converted them to strings and still null.

Comment: Side note: `(microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000` seems wrong. At the beginning, `$executionStartTime` is already divided by 1000, so here you're basically subtracting values of different orders of magnitude. I believe you wanted `microtime(true) / 1000 - $executionStartTime`.

Comment: When you dump `$result`, what do you get?

Comment: Thank you El_Vanja that made the result make more sense! How do you mean "dump" ?

Comment: I mean using `var_dump($result)` to get the contents of the variable. But tell me, do you really use backticks (`\``) when you build your url? PHP doesn't support that, those should be regular quotes (`'`).

Comment: Thank you El_Vanja that seems to have fixed it , I am used to Javascript notation that is why I used ` .

Comment: Actually PHP [does support backticks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), but certainly not for strings.